# Find the largest value of $n,n\in\mathbb{I^+}$ so that this equation involving greatest integer function holds true

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find the greatest positive integer value of $n$ such that $$\left[\frac{n}{3}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{35}\right]=\left[\frac{n}{5}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{7}\right]$$
> where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

---

We can rewrite the equation as $$\frac{n}{3}-\left\{\frac{n}{3}\right\}+\frac{n}{35}-\left\{\frac{n}{35}\right\}=\frac{n}{5}-\left\{\frac{n}{5}\right\}+\frac{n}{7}-\left\{\frac{n}{7}\right\}$$
where $\{x\}$ denotes fractional part of $x$.

This can rephrased as $$\frac{2n}{105}=\left\{\frac{n}{3}\right\}+\left\{\frac{n}{35}\right\}-\left\{\frac{n}{5}\right\}-\left\{\frac{n}{7}\right\}$$
$$\implies \frac{2n}{105}<2$$
$$\implies n<105$$

---

I'm stuck after this. How to proceed from here$?$ The solution that I have to this problem uses **trial and error** as the method. In general how to solve equations involving greatest integer function$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\{n/3\}\le2/3$, $\{n/35\}\le34/35$ may give you a slightly sharper bound.

Comment: You may be able to make the bound even sharper by noting that $\{n/5\}$ and $\{n/7\}$ have a relationship to $\{n/35\}$. For example, if $\{n/35\} = 34/35$, then neither $\{n/5\}$ nor$ \{n/7\}$ can be zero.

Comment: @eyeballfrog you're right...but unfortunately I'm not able to get the bound sharper...I used gerry's hint and arrived at the same bound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that as long as $n$ is not a multiple of $5$ or $7$, then decreasing $n$ by $1$ increases $\{n/35\}-\{n/5\}-\{n/7\}$ by $11/35$. Therefore, we know that whatever $n$ maximizes this, it is divisible by $5$ or $7$, and so $\{n/5\}+\{n/7\}$ is a multiple of $1/7$ or $1/5$. The first candidate is $n\equiv 30 \mod 35$, which gives $\{n/5\}+\{n/7\} = 2/7$. There are only two remainders that give a smaller value, $21$ and $15$, and both have a smaller value of $\{n/35\}-\{n/5\}-\{n/7\}$. Therefore, we have that
$$
\left\{\frac{n}{35} \right\}-\left\{\frac{n}{5}\right\}-\left\{\frac{n}{7}\right\}\le \frac{30}{35}-\frac{0}{5}-\frac{2}{7} = \frac{4}{7}
$$
Combining this with the bound $\{n/3\} \le 2/3$ gives
$$
n\le \frac{105}{2}\left(\frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{7}\right) = 65.
$$
And since $n= 65$ satisfies the equation, it is the largest such value.

Comment: As an addendum, I'm now curious about the general problem for maximizing $\{n/pq\}-\{n/p\}-\{n/q\}$ for primes $p,q$.

Comment: I'll have to study this answer thoroughly...and ofc 65 is the right answer :)